# Click to show textbox not working in select tag when repeating the form

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, laravel-8

On the 1st image link, when I click on others, a textbox will appears

[image: 1]

But On the 2nd image link after click on Add  button the textbox did not appear when click on others

[image: 2]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.repeater').repeater({
    repeaters: [{
      selector: '.inner-repeater'
    }]
  });
  $("[data-repeater-list]").on("change", "[name*=cqualificationtxtt]", function() {
    $(this).closest("div")
      .find("[name*=otherqualification]")
      .toggle(this.value==="others");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.repeater/1.2.1/jquery.repeater.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="repeater wd_100">
  <div data-repeater-list="data">
    <div data-repeater-item class="o_h mb_15">
      <div class="wd_12 fl_lf  mb_33">
        <label for="applicant_name" class="control-label lbl_hide"><b>Qualification</b>:</label>
        <select class="form-control" data-role="select-dropdown" name="cqualificationtxtt" >
          <option selected="">Select</option>
          <option value="b.tech">b.tech</option>
          <option value="mca">mca</option>
          <option value="others">Others</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="otherqualification" placeholder="Enter Qualification" style="display:none" />
      </div>
      <div class="wd_12 fl_lf mb_33">
        <label for="applicant_name" class="control-label lbl_hide"><b>college</b>:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="collagetxt">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input data-repeater-create type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" />
</div>
```

Comment: I made you the snippet you could have made using the `[<>]` snippet editor. The snippet does not show your issue. Please change the snippet to show your issue and explain how to recreate and expected outcome

Comment: IDs need to be unique

Comment: Thanks for made snippet **mplungjan**.

Comment: But as you see on the above snippet, when Someone  click on **Qualification  select tag** ,  "other" option will there. when click on other option a textbox will come . But When you click on **add button** again same qualification select tag will come and when you click on others option (which is inside qualification tag) then textbox didnot come. But it has to be shown. Please help me

Comment: $(".repeater wd_100").on("change","[name=cqualificationtxtt]", function() { $(this).closest("div").find("[name=color]").toggle(["pick a color","others"].includes(this.value)); }) --- This is not working

Comment: I know. Your repeater changes the names. I have updated your snippet with a working version

Comment: I changed the name from color to otherqualification and removed the pick a color. It did not belong in your code